# Journey behavior while shifting the conector to a different ORG

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We activated several journeys that were running properly with Marketing Cloud connected to a UAT ORG. Now that we have reconnected to the PRO ORG, it seems the journeys are not evaluating the records.

We have made sure to sync the same objects in the PRO ORG.

We are kind of panicking in case we have to set up the journeys from scratch. Any has experienced this? Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Going to take a guess here and say you are using Salesforce Data entry events? If so you will need to create a new version of the journey then reactivate. 
The reason is that when you activate a journey with Salesforce entry events you actually creat a process builder/flow in Salesforce which will need recreating in the new instance you have connected of SFDC. Activating a new version should trigger this creation.
You shouldn't need to recreate the entry event itself but it may pay to do it just in case.
Cheers